# Incrementing a session name if it is previously set

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to create a group of sessions that just store the amount of items that are ticked through a checkbox. These items need to be grouped and all come from from the same form.

Say I tick 3 boxes, then a session called, say,  `group_selection_1` and has a value of 3 should be created. Then I go back to the same form, select 5 check boxes this time then `group_selection_2` is made with a value of 5.

I'm having difficulty thinking of how this can be achieved. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want the sessions to be created on form submit? Or through ajax? or...?

Comment: @JakeParis The sessions are being created on a form submit. Their creation isn't a problem, it's incrementing their sessions name. I think I'll need to create another session or something, call it one and then check if it's set. If it is, ++1, or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// get all sessions
$sessions = $_SESSION;

if (!empty($sessions)) {
    // loop and check the session keys
    foreach ($sessions as $key => $value) {

        // match group_selection_* (* = any digits)
        if (preg_match('/group_selection_(?<num_key>\d)/im', $key, $matches)) {

            // session group_selection_* is existed
            if (isset($matches['num_key'])) {
                $increment = $matches['num_key'] + 1;
                $_SESSION['group_selection_' . $increment] = 'new thing...';
            } else {
                // not existed
                $_SESSION['group_selection_1'] = 'something....';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this is the exact sort of logic I was looking to achieve. Thank you.